# Apache mod_ssl to use OpenSSL ENGINE on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4, openssl

I have installed OpenSSL 1.0.1f and created an Engine for RSA acceleration using GPU. The Engine is dynamic so it is known globally.
Then I have installed Apache `$ sudo apt-get install apache2`, created self signed certificates in order to provide HTTPS services, modified the configuration files, etc.
These two parts work properly but separately, i.e. when I try to specify Apache to use the RSA engine (in OpenSSL 1.0.1f) it just fails with message:

```
* The apache2 configtest failed. Not doing anything.
Output of config test was:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf:
SSLCryptoDevice: Invalid argument; must be one of: 'builtin' (none), 'rsax' (RSAX engine support), 'dynamic' (Dynamic engine loading support)
```

So my questions:
Under Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit, is Apache using other version of OpenSSL then the version installed by me?
And how can I link the Apache with the OpenSSL in order to use that Engine?

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jan 14 2016 17:45:23
```

And the dynamic engines are:

```
root@dani-pc:/etc/apache2# openssl engine
(rsax) RSAX engine support
(dynamic) Dynamic engine loading support
(rsagpu) RSA GPU engine support
```

So I added `SSLCryptoDevice rsagpu` to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf` file and it fails, but `SSLCryptoDevice rsax` works great.

Comment: What argument did you put in the configuration?

Comment: Do you mean Apache configuration? If so, I put `SSLCryptoDevice id_of_engine` and returned the message above, but if I specify `SSLCryptoDevice rsax` it is all fine.

Comment: What output do you get from running `openssl engine` on the command line?

Comment: `(rsax) RSAX engine support  
(dynamic) Dynamic engine loading support  
(rsagpu) RSA GPU engine support  
` which is ok

Comment: According to the [package information](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/apache2-bin), Apache 2.4.7 on Ubuntu 14.04 depends on libssl1.0.0, which has its current version at 1.0.1f, so I'm not sure where to go from here, assuming that all of your packages are up to date.

Comment: So Apache comes with its own libssl and it doesn't use libssl installed by me?

Comment: Maybe I should install Apache from sources and specify `./configure --with-ssl=/etc/ssl/`. Later edit: the result is the same.

Comment: Apache installed from the package manager uses libssl installed from the package manager.

Comment: Today I have installed OpenSSL from sources, the Apache from sources specifying the OpenSSL directory, same message error although the new OpenSSL comes with many more default engines (4758cca, aep, atalla, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps that finally worked for me:

1.Install OpenSSL from sources, specifying `-DOPENSSL_LOAD_CONF` when running `./config`
1.1.Create/build your OpenSSL engine and add it to your `openssl.cnf` file
2.Install httpd from sources, using these commands:

```
CFLAGS='-DSSL_EXPERIMENTAL_ENGINE -DSSL_ENGINE -DOPENSSL_LOAD_CONF' ./configure --enable-ssl --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl --with-pcre=/usr/local/pcre --enable-so      
make       
make install
```

2.1.Edit `httpd-ssl.conf` by adding `SSLCryptoDevice engine_id` and make sure that when execute `$ openssl engine`, the `engine_id` specifier appears on the list. Also, you have to create self-signed cerificate and private key, modify the `httpd.conf` file, but this is not the subject of this question. Search: how to configure HTTPS on Apache.
3.`$ httpd -k restart` and that is all.